# What does Resource ID #114 on an PHP MySQL query mean?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code

```
 mysql_select_db('example_db', $r);
 $result1 = mysql_query('SELECT content FROM `example_table` WHERE 1') or die ('"bad times an error!"' . mysql_error() . '');
 echo $result1;
```

which returns "Resource ID #114". What does this mean? The info I'm trying to pull is a base64 & json encoded twitter feed stored in a DB. I've tried adding the base64 & json decoding, but get an error stating that it's a resource and not a string, so I assume it's trying to parse "Resource ID #114" rather than the actual feed itself.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: it means your query worked. you don't use the resource directly

Comment: OH DUH! I can't believe I overlooked this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have another look at the documentation: [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-query.php) will return an resource object. You have to work with it to extract the data. `mysql_fetch_array` or `mysql_fetch_assoc` will help you.

**WATCH OUT**:

You should not use the mysql_* - functions anymore. They are deprecated and will be not longer supported by >= php 5.5 . You should switch to [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

[Resources](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) are custom variables in php like (but different) [Streams](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.stream.php). You may read the documentation first:

> A resource is a special variable, holding a reference to an external
>   resource. Resources are created and used by special functions. See the
>   appendix for a listing of all these functions and the corresponding
>   resource types.

Second problem is you're using mysql_query() like deprecated and ancient methods. This is very bad. You should use other (more modern) interfaces (like [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) or mysqli) when interacting with db.

In your example, `$result1` is a resource, you can't print it like that. You have to iterate on it:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    echo $row['columnName'];
}
```